# Nagios plugin check_snmp_int does not match regular expression

Tags: regex, nagios

I am using nagios plugin check_snmp_int with -n switch. Help show:

```
-n, --name=NAME
   Name in description OID (eth0, ppp0 ...).
   This is treated as a regexp : -n eth will match eth0,eth1,...
   Test it before, because there are known bugs (ex : trailling /)
```

So It should work with regex but it does not look like. I try to match exact description of adapter "Marvell Yukon 88E8056 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller", but it gives me all adapters matching this string or nothing. I have also other adapters with names:

```
Marvell Yukon 88E8056 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller - Deterministic Network Enhancer Miniport
Marvell Yukon 88E8056 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller #2
...
```

I tried regex `Controller$`, which work well with grep command, but did not match anything with `check_snmp_int` command.

I tried also turn off regex with `-r switch`, but then did not found anything.

Any ideas how to solve that without changing description on adapter?

Comment: could you please add the exect regex you tried already (with qoutation)

you might need to do some additional qoutation or do \$ or similiar.

Comment: I tried theese:
    "Controller$"
    "Controller\$"
    "Controller\\$"
    Controller$
    Controller\$
    Controller\\$
    'Controller$'
    'Controller\$'
    'Controller\\$'

Comment: I found partial solution. Replace check_snmp_int with check_snmp_netint from http://exchange.nagios.org/index.php?option=com_mtree&task=viewlink&link_id=1475&Itemid=74                   But there is not working performance data generation with -f switch which I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution which works well also with performance data generation:

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_snmp_netint.pl -H xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -C public -n "Marvell Yukon 88E8056 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller$" -fZkz
```

You should now see output like this:

```
Marvell Yukon 88E8056 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller:UP (1.0KBps/7.0KBps) :(1 UP): OK |  'Marvell Yukon 88E8056 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller_in_octet'=275793073c 'Marvell Yukon 88E8056 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller_out_octet'=74278639c
```

When your graph do not work till now and you see output also with part after "|" , just delete old rrd and xml file for service located at:

```
/var/lib/pnp4nagios/perfdata
```

As you can see I used pnp4nagios as graphing tool. Hope this helps someone.